# Conditional Rendering on BottomTab Navigator not working

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, conditional-rendering

So what i am trying to do is that I am doing conditional rendering of my AccountStack and AuthStack on my AccountTab, now my AuthStack contains screens Welcome, Login and Otp and after entering the otp i want to navigate back to the Account Screen which is in my AccountStack but I am not getting navigated to Account screen instead I am getting stuck on Opt screen. it seems like my checkIfLoggedIn function is not getting called after successful login.

I want to know what I am doing wrong in my Code

Here are my BottomTabNavigator, AccountStack and AuthStack, Welcome, Login and Otp screen

```
const BottomNavigator = () => {
  const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator()
  // const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(true)
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  useFocusEffect(() => {
    const onScreenFocus = () => {
      setIsFocused(true)
      
    }

    navigation.addListener('focus', onScreenFocus)

    return () => {
      navigation.removeListener('focus', onScreenFocus)
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfLoggedIn()
  }, [])
  

  const checkIfLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
      console.log('value from bottomtab', value)
      if (value !== null) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  console.log('isLoggedI from bottomtab', isLoggedIn)
  const AccountScreenComponent = isLoggedIn ? AccountNavigator : AuthNavigator;

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      backBehavior='history'
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.secondary,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.primary,
        unmountOnBlur: true,
        tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
          if (isFocused) {
            navigation.popToTop()
          } else {
            defaultHandler()
          }
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: colors.background,
          borderTopWidth: ResponsivePixels.size1,
          borderTopColor: colors.divider2,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: ResponsivePixels.size42,
          paddingHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size10,
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          height: ResponsivePixels.size50,
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size10,
          fontFamily: 'Sarabun-SemiBold',
          // lineHeight: ResponsivePixels.size14,
        },
        tabBarIconStyle: {
          marginVertical: ResponsivePixels.size2,
        },
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={'Home'}
        component={HomeNavigator}
        options={{
          title: '',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            if (focused) {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: ResponsivePixels.size1,
                    paddingHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size5,
                    paddingVertical: ResponsivePixels.size4,
                    borderRadius: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                    borderColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={bottomHomeActvieIcon}
                    style={{
                      width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                      height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size3,
                      fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                      fontFamily: 'Sarabun-SemiBold',
                      color: colors.secondary,
                    }}>
                    Home
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={bottomHomeIcon}
                  style={{
                    width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          },
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={'Search'}
        component={SearchNavigator}
        options={{
          title: '',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <Image
              source={focused ? bottomSearchIcon : bottomSearchIcon}
              style={{
                width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
              }}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={'Order'}
        component={OrderNavigator}
        options={{
          title: '',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            if (focused) {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: ResponsivePixels.size1,
                    paddingHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size5,
                    paddingVertical: ResponsivePixels.size4,
                    borderRadius: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                    borderColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={bottomOrderActiveIcon}
                    style={{
                      width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                      height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size3,
                      fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                      fontFamily: 'Sarabun-SemiBold',
                      color: colors.secondary,
                    }}>
                    Order
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={bottomOrderIcon}
                  style={{
                    width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          },
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={'Basket'}
        component={BasketNavigator}
        options={{
          title: '',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            if (focused) {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: ResponsivePixels.size1,
                    paddingHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size5,
                    paddingVertical: ResponsivePixels.size4,
                    borderRadius: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                    borderColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={bottomBasketActiveIcon}
                    style={{
                      width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                      height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size3,
                      fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                      fontFamily: 'Sarabun-SemiBold',
                      color: colors.secondary,
                    }}>
                    Basket
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={bottomBasketIcon}
                  style={{
                    width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          },
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={'Account'}
        component={AccountScreenComponent}
        initialParams={{fromBasketScreen: false}}
        options={{
          title: '',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            if (focused) {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: ResponsivePixels.size1,
                    paddingHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size5,
                    paddingVertical: ResponsivePixels.size4,
                    borderRadius: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                    borderColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryContainer,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={bottomAccountActiveIcon}
                    style={{
                      width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                      height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size3,
                      fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                      fontFamily: 'Sarabun-SemiBold',
                      color: colors.secondary,
                    }}>
                    {isLoggedIn ? 'Account' : 'Login'}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={bottomAccountIcon}
                  style={{
                    width: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    height: ResponsivePixels.size25,
                    marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size8,
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          },
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  )
}
export default BottomNavigator
```

```
 const AccountNavigator = () => {
  const AccountStack = createStackNavigator()


  
  return (
    <AccountStack.Navigator initialRouteName={ACCOUNT} screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <AccountStack.Screen name={ACCOUNT} component={Account} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={PROFILE} component={Profile} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={MY_ADDRESS} component={MyAddressess} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={ADD_ADDRESS} component={AddNewAddress} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={MY_SHOPPINGLIST} component={ShoppingList} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={HELP_CENTER} component={HelpCenter} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={ORDER_SUCCESSFUL} component={OrderPlaced} />
      <AccountStack.Screen name={FAQ} component={Faqs} />
    </AccountStack.Navigator>
  )
}
export default AccountNavigator;
```

```
const AuthNavigator = () => {
    const AuthStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    return (
        <AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
            <AuthStack.Screen name={WELCOME} component={Welcome}  initialParams={{ fromBasketScreen: false }} />
            <AuthStack.Screen name={LOGIN} component={Login} />
            <AuthStack.Screen name={OTP} component={OtpScreen}/>
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );
};
export default AuthNavigator;
```

```
const Welcome = ({onChangedText, value, loading, onSubmit}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const route = useRoute()

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
      tabBarStyle: {
        display: 'none',
      },
    })
    return () =>
      navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
        tabBarStyle: undefined,
      })
  }, [navigation])

  const handleLogin = () => {
    navigation.navigate(LOGIN, {
        fromBasketScreen: route.params?.fromBasketScreen,
    })
    console.log('fromBasketScreen welcome', route.params?.fromBasketScreen)
  }

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={welcomeImage} style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar
        translucent
        backgroundColor='transparent'
        barStyle={'dark-content'}
      />
      <View style={styles.loginWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.welcomeLabel}>
          <Text style={styles.welcomeLabel}>Welcome to</Text>
          <Text style={styles.logoLabel}>NNT Mart</Text>
          <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.mobileText}>Enter your{'\n'}mobile number</Text>
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
              <Image style={{marginStart: 12}} source={flagIcon} />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontFamily: 'Sarabun-Regular',
                  marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size12,
                  color: colors.onTextMedium,
                }}>
                + 91
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                placeholder='00000 00000'
                value={value}
                style={styles.textInput}
                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                onPressIn={handleLogin}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.cbWrapper}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: HOME})}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.primary,
                paddingLeft: loading ? ResponsivePixels.size5 : 0,
                fontFamily: 'Prompt-Medium',
                fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size14,
              }}>
              Continue as guest
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  )
}
export default Welcome
```

```
const Login = () => {
  const route = useRoute()
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('')
  const [isValueValid, setIsValueValid] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  const handleInputChange = inputValue => {
    setMobileNumber(inputValue)
    if (inputValue.length === 10 && /^\d+$/.test(inputValue)) {
      setIsValueValid(true)
    } else {
      setIsValueValid(false)
    }
  }

  const handleContinue = () => {
    console.log('Navigating to OTP screen');
    setIsLoading(true)
    dispatch(postLogin(mobileNumber))
      .then(result => {
        console.log('result', result)

        if (!result.error) {
          navigation.navigate(OTP, {
            fromBasketScreen: route.params?.fromBasketScreen,
          })
          console.log(
            'fromBasketScreen login',
            route.params?.fromBasketScreen,
          )
        } else {
          console.log(result.error)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error===>>>', error)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }

  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true)
  }

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.welcomeContentContainer}>
      <Header leftIcon='back' />
      <Text style={styles.welcomeTextHeader}>
        Enter your{'\n'}mobile number
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>We will send you a OTP code</Text>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.loginInputContainer,
          isFocused && styles.loginInputContainerFocused,
        ]}>
        <Image
          style={{marginStart: ResponsivePixels.size12}}
          source={flagIcon}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            marginLeft: ResponsivePixels.size12,
            color: colors.onTextMedium,
          }}>
          + 91
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='00000 00000'
          placeholderTextColor={colors.onTextLow}
          value={mobileNumber}
          onChangeText={handleInputChange}
          style={styles.loginInput}
          keyboardType='phone-pad'
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
        {console.log('mobileNumber:::', mobileNumber)}
      </View>
      {isLoading && (
        <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
          <CommonLoader />
        </View>
      )}
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <CustomButton
          title='Continue '
          primary
          disabled={!isValueValid}
          onPress={handleContinue}
        />
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>
          By Clicking to continue, you accept our{' '}
          <Text style={{color: colors.primary}}>terms</Text> and{' '}
          <Text style={{color: colors.primary}}>condition</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Login
```

```
const OtpScreen = () => {
  const route = useRoute()
  const fromBasketScreen = route.params?.fromBasketScreen || false
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState({})
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(10)
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false)
  const minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60)
  const seconds = remainingTime % 60
  const [otpCode, setOtpCode] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMobileNumber())
      .then(data => {
        setPhone(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }, [dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (remainingTime > 0) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setRemainingTime(prevRemainingTime => prevRemainingTime - 1)
      }, 1000)
      return () => clearTimeout(timer)
    } else {
      setShowButton(true)
    }
  }, [remainingTime])

  const handleOtpCodeChange = code => {
    console.log('OTP code entered:', code);
    if (code.length === 4 && code === '1234') {
      console.log('fromBasketScreen', fromBasketScreen)
      if (fromBasketScreen) {
        navigation.navigate('Basket', {
          screen: BASKET,
          params: {fromBasketScreen: true},
        })
      console.log('fromBasketScreen', fromBasketScreen)
      } else {
        navigation.navigate('Account', {
          screen: ACCOUNT,
          params: {fromBasketScreen: false},
        })
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.otpContainer}>
      <View style={styles.otpContentContainer}>
        <Header leftIcon='back' />
        <Text style={styles.otpTextHeader}>
          Enter OTP{'\n'}sent to your number
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.otpText}>
          We sent it to the number +91 {phone.mobileNumber}
        </Text>

        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: ResponsivePixels.size16,
            marginHorizontal: ResponsivePixels.size10,
            width: '96%',
            height: '2%',
          }}>
          <OTPInputView
            pinCount={4}
            autoFocusOnLoad
            codeInputFieldStyle={styles.underlineStyleHighLighted}
            onCodeChanged={handleOtpCodeChange}
            placeholderCharacter='•'
            placeholderTextColor={colors.onTextLow}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.resendText}>
          {showButton ? (
            <CustomButton
              title='Resend'
              primary
              onPress={() => setRemainingTime(10)}
            />
          ) : (
            <Text
              style={{
                color: colors.onTextLow,
                fontFamily: 'Sarabun-Medium',
                fontSize: ResponsivePixels.size16,
              }}>
              Resend code in{' '}
              <Text style={{color: colors.darkBlue}}>
                {String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:
                {String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}
              </Text>
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
export default OtpScreen
```